# how to get age with localdate by instantiate

Tags: java, junit

How can I got the age with localdate  using the set of the instantiate, i ve try using localdate with set age and it doesnt work. ive tried to put the age as an LocalDate instead of an Int, but it doesnt work too, im a new programmer, i hope you guys could help me solve this.Its a compile error

```
  package main;
    import Usuarios.User;
    import java.time.LocalDate;
    /**
     *
     * @author Gustavo
     */
    public class Main {
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    
            User person1 = new User();
            person1.setName("Mike");
            person1.setbirthdateUser(LocalDate.of(1970, 5, 17));
            person1.setAge(LocalDate.now().getYear() - birthdateUser.getYear());
    
            /*person1.age = LocalDate.now().getYear() - person1.birthdateUser.getYear();*/
    
            System.out.println(person1.getName() + " has " +  person1.getAge() + " years old");
```

---

Comment: Are you asking how to get rid of the compile error on line 16, or how to do the calculation to make the age correct?

Comment: Question is incomplete: What's `setAge`? Paste that code. What are you asking? Note that your age calculation is broken, _AND_ you have a remarked-out line which also seems broken / you are mixing field access and setters/getters which, if that is not an outright compiler error, is rather bizarre class design. Question can't be answered without a lot more detail.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I think it's clear what's in the `User` class - there'll be getters and setters for name, birthDate and age.  We don't need to see those.  And if Gustavo tried to paste them in, he might reach the problem where Stack Overflow forbids a question with too much code and not enough text.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem your right, its getters and setters, like any project. Feel free to make the age correct, i thought i was on a way, but its seems i did the code completely wrong

Comment: i thought i could get the age with just localdate, i have to make some method?

Comment: Given that it's evidently about a compiler error, it's specifically relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiling error in this line:

```
person1.setAge(LocalDate.now().getYear() - birthdateUser.getYear());
```

is due to the fact that `birthdateUser.getYear()` didn't use the `Person` object `person1` to invoke the method. That should've been

```
person1.setAge(LocalDate.now().getYear() - person1.getBirthdateUser().getYear());
```

That said, in my opinion, setting `age` on the object is not necessary. It is better to pass the birth date and have the object calculate the age based on this piece of data. So, my solution for this (using Java record) is as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "Mike";
        LocalDate birthdate = LocalDate.of(1970, 5, 17);
        User person1 = new User(name, birthdate);
        System.out.println(person1.name() + ", born in " + person1.birthdate + ", is " +  person1.age() + " years old");
    }
    
    private static record User (String name, LocalDate birthdate) {
        
        public long age() {
            return ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(birthdate, LocalDate.now());
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
Mike, born in 1970-05-17, is 51 years old
```

Notice how, even though I am using a record, I can still create a custom method that returns the age based on the birth date passed to the object being invoked. This is actually pretty cool because, even though the age changes, because I am not storing it, it doesn't violate the constraint of the object being "immutable" because age is not a field in the record. It is a calculated value. This makes this object inherently thread safe (not totally).

**UPDATE**: A slightly better version with more utility methods.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "Mike";
        LocalDate birthdate = LocalDate.of(1970, 5, 17);
        User person1 = new User(name, birthdate);
        System.out.println(person1.toString());
        System.out.println(person1.name() + " was born on a " + person1.getDayBornOn());
    }
    
    private static record User (String name, LocalDate birthdate) {
        
        public long age() {
            return ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(birthdate, LocalDate.now());
        }
        
        public int getBirthYear() {
            return birthdate.getYear();
        }
        
        public String getBirthdateMonth() {
            return capitalizeFirstLetter(birthdate.getMonth().toString());
        }
        
        public String getBirthday() {
            return getBirthdateMonth() + " " + birthdate.getDayOfMonth();
        }
        
        public String getDateOfBirth() {
            return getBirthday() + ", " + getBirthYear();
        }
        
        public String getDayBornOn() {
            
            return capitalizeFirstLetter(birthdate.getDayOfWeek().name());
        }
        
        private String capitalizeFirstLetter(String string) {
            string = string.toLowerCase();
            String upperLetter = String.valueOf(string.charAt(0)).toUpperCase();
            return upperLetter + string.substring(1);
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.name() + ", born in " + this.getDateOfBirth() + ", is " +  this.age() + " years old";
        }
    }
}
```

Now this outputs:

```
Mike, born in May 17, 1970, is 51 years old
Mike was born on a Sunday
```

Comment: the variables must be private(name,birthdateUser)

Comment: it would work with private?

Comment: With what private? I don't know what you mean.

Comment: someone closed my question, do you know how to get it back?the question is right and you answered!

Comment: @GustavoSantos edit the question. And, as the message states "_Add details and clarify the problem being solved_". To be honest, I have yet to see a question being reopen. I have been victim of the same (premature) closing of questions. I have appeal with no luck. But, you might have better luck. I will raise a flag to reopen the question once you edit it. In addition to "_It's a compiler error_", you should add the actual error, for example, the stack trace message.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            
    LocalDate birthDate = LocalDate.of(1970, 5, 17);
    LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
    int age = Period.between(birthDate, currentDate).getYears();

    System.out.println("Age is: " + age);
   }
```